# Book where a kid playing baseball gains super speed and knocks over the seating stand

Tags: story-identification, books, super-hero

When I was younger I read this book about superheroes. Its protagonist gained super speed during a childhood baseball game and knocked over the seating stand. It was kind of in a similar vein to the film *Zoom*.

Comment: _"When I was younger"_ what was that? Was this a novel, novella? Was it part of a series? Was it aimed at a younger audience? How did he gain superspeed? What happened after? Did he fight crime, become evil? You say superheroes? So were there more? What were their powers? Can you remember any of the plot after this? If you remember anything else please [edit] those details into the question itself.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Might it be Clarke Baldwin's [*My Baseball Teammates are Half Cheetah*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DE6VP5G)?

> Chance Bradley wants to be starting pitcher for his town’s baseball team but he just can’t seem to get to that next level. He and his friends volunteer for a scientific experiment that is supposed to make them faster and stronger. Chance wakes up to a whole new way of life that involves super speed and some unexpected side effects. It’s a jungle out there in the baseball playoffs.

Found with a search for `book boy superspeed baseball`